# Result even after crossing the limit of the initialized array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

After initialization of an array up to certain limit and then printing the array out of that limit it is still printing the result.Why ?

```
Example :

    #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     int main() {
        int A[2] = {};
        cout << A[0] << "\n";
        cout << A[1] << "\n";
        cout << A[2] << "\n";
        cout << A[3] << "\n";
        cout << A[4] << "\n";
        return 0;
   }
```

The Output is:

```
    0
    0
    0
    0
   -13120
```

Here I have just initialized the array till 2 places. But still I am getting the result of A[2],A[3] and so on.

Comment: "undefined behavior".

Comment: You should learn more about array.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour (which this is) can do *anything*.

Comment: I have used the Scala and other languages where in this case out of bound kind of error is shown. I just want to know the reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 4):

Crossing the limit results in undefined behavior (UB). It can print and looks like working normally, it could crash, it could stuck,or it could be anything.

So, you should not rely on it if it works sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Exceeding an array's bounds is undefined behaviour. This means that the program may do simply nothing, may print something, may exit the program, may ... behaviour is simply not defined.
So printing out something is still one possible behaviour, but you must not rely on this behaviour.